# variable std::fstream file has initializer but incomplete type Compilation error

Tags: c++, c++11, file-io, fstream

This is the file where the compiler shows where the error is. I have searched the same error online, most of them is caused by not including the< fstream >, but here I have included it, it still showing this error.

I forgot to add, in Visual Studio everything compiled with no problems, but when I uploaded it to my school matrix, it showed compilation error, and message is
"variable std::fstream file has initializer but incomplete type".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "MyFile.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace sict;
int main() {
    fstream file("ms3.txt", ios::out);
    file << "one" << endl << "two" << endl;
    file.close();
    MyFile F("ms3.txt");
    F.load(file);
    cout << "Linear: " << F << endl;
    cout << "As is: " << endl;
    F.print();
    cout << "Enter the following: " << endl << "three<ENTER>" << endl <<     "four<ENTER>" << endl << "Ctrl-Z<ENTER>" << endl << endl;
    cin >> F;
    F.store(file, true);
    F.load(file);
    cout << F << endl;
    F.print();
    return 0;
}
```

This is my MyFile.h, and MyFile.cpp

```
#ifndef SICT_MYFILE_H__
#define SICT_MYFILE_H__
#include "Streamable.h"
#include "Streamable.h"
#include "Streamable.h" // Streamable.h is included three times on purpose.
namespace sict {
    class MyFile : public Streamable {
        char fname_[256];
        char text_[10000];
    public:
        MyFile(const char* fname);
        std::fstream& store(std::fstream& file, bool addNewLine)const;
        std::fstream& load(std::fstream& file);
        std::ostream& write(std::ostream& os, bool linear)const;
        std::istream& read(std::istream& is);
        void print();
     };
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostr, const MyFile& mf);
    std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& istr, MyFile& mf);
}
#endif
```

MyFile.cpp

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include "MyFile.h"
using namespace std;
namespace sict {

    MyFile::MyFile(const char* fname) {
        text_[0] = char(0);
        strcpy(fname_, fname);
    }
    fstream& MyFile::store(std::fstream& file, bool addNewLine)const {
        file.open(fname_, ios::app | ios::out);
        int i = 0;
        while (text_[i]) {
            file << text_[i];
            i++;
        }
        file.close();
        return file;
    }
    fstream& MyFile::load(std::fstream& file) {
        file.open(fname_, ios::in);
        int i = 0;
        while (!file.fail()) {
            text_[i++] = file.get();
        }
        file.clear();
        file.close();
        if (i > 0) i--;
        text_[i] = 0;
        return file;
    }
    ostream& MyFile::write(std::ostream& os, bool linear)const {
        for (int i = 0; text_[i]; i++) {
            if (linear && text_[i] == '\n') {
                os << " ";
            }
            else {
                os << text_[i];
            }
        }
        return os;
    }
    istream& MyFile::read(std::istream& is) {
        is.getline(text_, 9999, EOF);
        return is;
    }
    void MyFile::print() {
        write(cout, false);
        cout << endl;
    }
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostr, const MyFile& mf) {
        return mf.write(ostr, true);
    }
    std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& istr, MyFile& mf) {
        return mf.read(istr);
    }
}
```

The MyFile.h and MyFile.cpp were given, so I was not suppose to edit anything, I also added an interface for the 4 pure virtual functions in Streamable.h.

```
#ifndef SICT_STREAMABLE_H__
#define SICT_STREAMABLE_H__

namespace sict {
    class Streamable {
    public:
        virtual std::fstream& store(std::fstream& file, bool addNewLine)const = 0;
        virtual std::fstream& load(std::fstream& file) = 0;
        virtual std::ostream& write(std::ostream& os, bool linear)const = 0;
        virtual std::istream& read(std::istream& is) = 0;
    };
}

#endif
```

Comment: You should post complete error description here. Also this error probably have something to do with "MyFile.h" so you should post it here as well.

Comment: We can only guess that having two `using namespace` brings in some conflicting names.

Comment: Please read how to provide a [mcve]!

Comment: where is compiler error message?

Comment: Myfile.h depends on fstream. You need an include. So does Streamable.

Answer (score 0):

This make no sense at all: `#include "Streamable.h" // Streamable.h is included three times on purpose.` In fact, it will do nothing except waste compilation time as you prevent multiple inclusions with `#ifndef SICT_STREAMABLE_H__` anyway.

Also, a good habit is to **always include the matched header file first** (only after precompiled header file when it applies). That way, you know that header like `MyFile.h` has any necessary includes to compile for any source file (provided that you don't do weird things).

Thus `MyFile.cpp` should start with:

```
    #include "MyFile.h"
```